# Firebase authentication with strings

Tags: firebase

I am wondering if it's possible to do the firebase authentication on strings? I have seen it being done on keys like `-XDhabsuduydvtest` <- random test key.
Now i have this structure:

```
{
  "conversations" : {
    "person1" : {
      "person2" : {
        "0" : 0,
        "last_read" : 1460377167535
      }
    },
    "person2" : {
      "person1" : {
        "0" : 0,
        "last_read" : 1460377125515
      }
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "eb-uuid-729fc0ac-49b8-48fa-a2ff-f2ada67b9e4c-person1" : {
      "body" : "Dit is een test vanuit iOS",
      "date" : 1460383996536,
      "sender" : "eb-uuid-729fc0ac-49b8-48fa-a2ff-f2ada67b9e4c"
    },
    "person1-person2" : {
      "-KF49xHKqnDawywJ9H0b" : {
        "body" : "test message",
        "date" : 1460375639190,
        "sender" : "person1"
      },
      "-KF4Fc1KHH31O4_l0QWh" : {
        "body" : "new",
        "date" : 1460377125013,
        "sender" : "person2"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "eb-uuid-729fc0ac-49b8-48fa-a2ff-f2ada67b9e4c" : {
      "chat_enabled" : true,
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "first_name" : "John",
      "last_name" : "Smith",
      "provider" : "password",
      "push_muted" : false,
      "push_token" : "some-push-token",
      "uid" : "729fc0ac-49b8-48fa-a2ff-f2ada67b9e4c",
      "username" : "johnsmith"
    },
    "person1" : {
      "first_name" : "person",
      "last_name" : "one"
    },
    "person2" : {
      "first_name" : "person",
      "last_name" : "two"
    }
  }
}
```

plus some security rule i tried, obviously i'd like to check if the uuid's are the same, and not only if one exists

```
{
    "rules": {
        "messages": {
          "$conv":{
            //Person can only read a conversation he/she is participating in
            ".write": true,
            ".read": true,
            ".indexOn": ["date"] 
          }
        },
        "users":{
          "$ebuuid":{
              ".write": "root.child('users').child($ebuuid).hasChild('uid')",
              ".read": "root.child('users').child($ebuuid).hasChild('uid')"
          }
        },
        "conversations":{
          ".write": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
          ".read":  true
        }
    }
}
```

(Replaced images with text)
I'm really not sure how to go from here now .. the user has some uid but i'm not sure how to check it with whether he or she can post messages etc ..

Comment: Authentication is when a user identifies themselves, so that the system knows who they are. Authorization is ensuring that users can only access the data you want them to be able to access. I assume you are talking about authorization here. But I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you show the security rules that you've already tried?

Comment: Well, the idea of the chat that i'm making is that there is some Email & Password authentication. I have done that in Firebase, and have some User UID in the column there. For the next step, I would like to check whether the user can post a message or read data from certain places. I have updated the structure above, it's basically `messages`/`some-uuid-here` and then the data. What i would like to accomplish is to check the uid's against eachother to determine if the user can access that data (updating the original post now)

Comment: There are too many screenshots of text here. Please replace them with the actual text, which (in the case of the JSON) you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the actual text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okay, just replaced the images with text

Comment: The `ebuuid` seems just a padded version of `uid`. Why is that? The reason I'm asking is that security rules usually get a lot easier if you store the users under their `uid`.

Comment: Yeah the `ebuuid` is almost the same, except for reasons I shortened the 'eb'. The reason for it to be like this is because it is coming from some external ticket system and the iOS dev throws it in Firebase like that. Would there be a solution to this, or would you highly recommend using a uid as key (i'd prefer not to, since my superior defined this structure ..)